# Tour improvement proposal: add a ⚠ markers to the guideline items

Tags: discussion, tour-page

Currently, almost all SE sites have their on-topic block in their tour consisting of items with X and √ markers. In this sense, the SR on-topic block has much important info that can be easily overlooked (well, I did until another guy in SO Meta discussion pointed it to me):

[image]

It seems to me if the 3 paragraphs were instead "list items" with ⚠ bullets, they will catch more attention. Here's a rough draft:

[image]

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

Good idea, I would say :-)

It makes these very important points more visible.

Comment: by the way, SO has its own ⚠ icons, see https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/developer-story/timeline.svg ; but I don't know what's the license/usage conditions and if there's closer ones to the ticks in terms of typographics